# javosize.jar can't decompile class

Tags: java

OS:Windows 7
Java Version:8

When i use command 'cat aaa.bbb.Use.class'.i got error msg as below
No code available. ByteCode of class aaa.bbb.Use.class not found at agent. More info at agent log.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: The reason could be that your application is running using JRE instead of JDK. javOSize requires JDK for cat command. Please, could you confirm if your are running your Java app with JDK? If it doesn't solve the issue, please, could you share with us the log traces? The default "agent log" is the standard output of your monitored application, you just have to check the javOSize messages there.